# Weird syntax with continue

Tags: python, syntax-error, continue

My question concern the code that was posted in this question [Questions about a tic-tac-toe program I am writing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50130343/7529716).

More precisely this line:

```
stop = int(0)# 0 = continue
```

First I didn't understand what he was trying to do and thought that it was a `SyntaxError`. But when I tried to execute this line, it didn't raise a `SyntaxError`, it just set stop to 0. Note this line is not inside a loop.

```
>>> stop = int(0)# 0 = continue
>>> stop
0
```

But this, as I expected, raise a error:

```
>>> int(0) = continue
File "<stdin>", line 1
  int(0) = continue
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Do someone know why that line is valied, thanx.

Comment: `#` is a comment. Everything after that is ignored.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see the #

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`#` introduces a *comment.* Everything after it is a comment and has no meaning to the Python interpreter. The comment is likely trying to say *"zero means to continue"*.

[PEP8 advises](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#comments) that *"inline comments should be separated by at least two spaces from the statement"*, which would probably have removed some confusion here.

Comment: Didn't see the # sorry